# Why do non-exhaustive guards cause irrefutable pattern match to fail?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, guard

I have this function in Haskell:

```
test :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
test a b
  | a == b = Just a
test _ _ = Nothing
```

This is what I got when I tried the function with different inputs:

```
ghci>test 3 4
Nothing
ghci>test 3 3
Just 3
```

According to Real World Haskell, the first pattern is irrefutable.  But it seems like `test 3 4` doesn't fails the first pattern, and matches the second.  I expected some kind of error -- maybe 'non-exhaustive guards'.  So what is really going on here, and is there a way to enable compiler warnings in case this accidentally happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first pattern is indeed an "irrefutable pattern", however this does not mean that it will always choose the corresponding right hand side of your function. It is still subject to the guard which may fail as it does in your example.

To ensure all cases are covered, it is common to use `otherwise` to have a final guard which will always succeed.

```
test :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
test a b
  | a == b    = Just a
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Note that there is nothing magic about `otherwise`. It is defined in the Prelude as `otherwise = True`. However, it is idiomatic to use `otherwise` for the final case.

Having a compiler warn about non-exaustive guards would be impossible in the general case, as it would involve solving the halting problem, however there exist tools like [Catch](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/catch/) which attempt to do a better job than the compiler at determining whether all cases are covered or not in the common case.

Comment: So if it's an irrefutable pattern, how does it fail to match?  Does matching depend on the success of the guards?  Does it first match, and then unmatch after the guard fails?

Comment: @Matt: The pattern does indeed match, and any variables bound by it are then made available to the guard, which may then fail. When this happens, the remaining guards are tried in order. If they all fail, the next pattern is tried. If there are no more patterns left to try, you get a non-exhaustive pattern match error.

Comment: In GHC `otherwise` *is* special. If you try defining it yourself, you'll end up with non-exhaustive match compile time warnings (provided you enable those warnings, of course).

Answer (score 6):

The compiler should be warning you if you leave out the second clause, i.e. if your last match has a set of guards where the last one is not trivially true.

Generally, testing guards for completeness is obviously not possible, as it would be as hard as solving the halting problem.

Answer to Matt's comment:

Look at the example:

```
foo a b 
   | a <= b = True
   | a >  b = False
```

A human can see that one of both guards must be true. But the compiler does not know that either `a <= b` or `a > b`.

Now look for another example:

```
fermat a b c n 
    | a^n + b^n /= c^n = ....
    | n < 0 = undefined
    | n < 3 = ....
```

To prove that the set of guards is complete, the compiler had to prove Fermat's Last Theorem. It's impossible to do that in a compiler. Remember that the number and complexity of the guards is not limited. The compiler would have to be a general solver for mathematical problems, problems that are stated in Haskell itself.

More formally, in the easiest case:

```
 f x | p x = y
```

the compiler must prove that if `p x` is not bottom, then `p x` is `True` for all possible x. In other words, it must prove that either `p x` is bottom (does not halt) no matter what `x` is or evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Could you explain more about why it is not possible?  I'm familiar with the halting problem, but don't see why this is obviously impossible.

Comment: I like the example using [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), which for the uninitiated, is one of the most famous problems in mathematics, and was not proven until 1995 (although Fermat claimed to have a proof which was too large to fit the margin).

Comment: In the presence of typeclasses, the situation is even worse. In your first example, the compiler would have to prove that either `a <= b` or `a > b` without even having the implementations of `<=` or `>` available! (Indeed, proving this is obviously impossible, since it's not necessarily even true in the face of badly-written instances.)

Comment: @Daniel - very true. Though one could argue that if one could prove or disprove theorems like _forall x.p x || q x_, then it would also be possible and a great feature to enrich a calss definition by laws the instances must follow such as _forall a b. a < b && not (b <= a) || a >= b && not (b > a)_

Comment: `It's impossible do do that in a compiler.` I'm sure it's not /impossible/ so to speak. Just not practical.

Answer (score 1):

Guards aren't irrefutable. But is very common (and good) practise to add one last guard that catch the other cases, so your function becomes:

```
test :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
test a b
  | a == b = Just a
  | True = Nothing
```